# React - get time of long pressing button in seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, intervals

I'm trying to return the number of seconds whilst holding in a button.

eg: "click+ hold, inits -> counts & displays 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 -> leaves button -> resets back to 0"

I've gotten close. It works fine, in my console, but whenever I try to update the state it ends up in an infinite loop.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Emergency = () => {
  let counter = 0;
  let timerinterval;

  const [ms, setMs] = useState(counter);

  const timer = start => {
    console.log("tick tock");
    console.log(start);
    if (start === true && counter >= 1) {
      timerinterval = setInterval(() => {
        counter += 1;
        console.log(counter);
        setMs(counter); //When I remove this, the infinite loop disappears.
      }, [1000]);
    } else {
      setMs(0);
    }
  };

  const pressingDown = e => {
    console.log("start");
    e.preventDefault();
    counter = 1;
    timer(true);
  };

  const notPressingDown = e => {
    console.log("stop");
    e.preventDefault();
    timer(false);
    setMs(0);
    clearInterval(timerinterval);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onMouseDown={pressingDown}
        onMouseUp={notPressingDown}
        onTouchStart={pressingDown}
        onTouchEnd={notPressingDown}
        className="button is-primary mt-3"
      >
        Emergency
      </button>
      <br />
      Time holding it is.... {ms}
    </>
  );
};

export default Emergency;
```

An easy way would be to calculate the time difference between mouseDown and mouseUp, but for the sake of UX, I would like to {ms} to update live as I'm holding the button.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: instead of `setInterval` you could do it with `window.performance.now()` and calculate the difference

Comment: I don't wanna calculate the difference though.. I want to calculate it 'live'...  eg, 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 etc etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- You are not clearing interval. `timeInterval` is a new variable whenever your component is re-rendered. You need to use `ref` (`const timeInterval = React.useRef(null); ... timeInterval.current = ... ; clearInterval(timeInterval.current);`
- Also you need to remove `counter = 1;` from your `pressingDowm` function, because before each `setMs` you are incrementing it by one

```
const Emergency = () => {
  let counter = 0;
  let timerinterval = React.useRef((null as unknown) as any);

  const [ms, setMs] = React.useState(counter);

  const timer = (start: any) => {
    console.log('tick tock');
    console.log(start);
    if (start === true && counter >= 1) {
      timerinterval.current = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(counter);
        setMs(counter); //When I remove this, the infinite loop disappears.
        counter += 1;
        //@ts-ignore
      }, [1000]);
    } else {
      setMs(0);
    }
  };

  const pressingDown = (e: any) => {
    console.log('start');
    e.preventDefault();
    counter = 1;
    timer(true);
  };

  const notPressingDown = (e: any) => {
    console.log('stop');
    e.preventDefault();
    timer(false);
    setMs(0);
    clearInterval(timerinterval.current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onMouseDown={pressingDown}
        onMouseUp={notPressingDown}
        onTouchStart={pressingDown}
        onTouchEnd={notPressingDown}
        className="button is-primary mt-3"
      >
        Emergency
      </button>
      <br />
      Time holding it is.... {ms}
    </>
  );
};
```

This is edited code (with some TypeScript stuff, sorry for that)

Comment: *** Also there is a functionality note! I'm not sure what are you counting exactly, but with this code, note that you are not clearing interval, in case if user presses down mouse click on <button /> and moves mouse and releases mouse click outside of <button />